# biblatex-apa customization

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I searched for an answer online but have not been able to find any.
I am trying to customize the `biblatex-apa` standard style so that I get the following.

When using `\parencite` I would like to get

> (Schmidt and Wesson, 2015)

and **not**

> (Schmidt & Wesson, 2015)

And in the bibliography, I would like to have names listed as

> Schmidt, S., Wesson, R., 2015. Early 21st century movements in society.

**not**

> Schmidt, S., & Wesson, R. (2015). Early 21st century movements in society.

A summary of my related code in the `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\begin{document}
I refer to \parencite{schmidt2015early} to highlight my point.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And in the `references.bib` I have:

```
@article{schmidt2015early,
title={Early 21st century movements in society},
author={Schmidt, S and Wesson, R},
year={2015}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can obtain the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` was written specifically to implement all requirements of the APA citation and reference/bibliography style as closely as possible with `biblatex`. The style is not supposed to be customised and it was not written with customisability in mind. Its sole purpose is to produce APA-compliant output.

That does not mean that no customisations are possible at all, but that even seemingly minute things can be tricky. If you want to write your own style, I strongly suggest you base it on one of the standard styles. The standard styles are supposed to be customisable and are supposed to be a basis for further modifications.

Anyway, here is what you can do to `biblatex-apa` to get what you want. It is not as straightforward as it would be with standard `biblatex` styles like `authoryear` (think `nameyeardelim`, `biblatex-ext`'s `biblabeldate` format, no need for `finalnamedelim:apa:family-given` etc.).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{finalnamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{apadate}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdatecirca} or test {\ifdateuncertain} }
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{author}\AND\ifnameundef{groupauthor}}
    {\ifnameundef{editor}
      {\usebibmacro{title}%
        % need to clear all title fields so we don't get them again later
        \clearfield{title}%
       \clearfield{subtitle}%
       \clearfield{titleaddon}}
      {\usebibmacro{editorinauthpos}}}
    {\usebibmacro{author}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{labelyear+extradate}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem \parencite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998)//Sigfridsson, E., Ryde, U., 1998. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI) 1096-987X(199803)19:4⟨377::AID-JCC1⟩3.0.CO;2-P]

Comment: Awesome answer! I am using Overleaf with XeLaTeX and using your example I am unfortunately getting an error at line 7 (\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. Also, on the top of the page I get: ib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}ib]{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{finalnamedelim and then below that: Lorem(Sigfridson and Ryde, 1998). Lastly the Reference doesn't show as your one, but still has the &: Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U., 1998.

Comment: @henkth Overleaf has an older version of TeX Live where you need to use `\DeclareDelimAlias*[bib]` instead of `\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]` in the two lines of the code above that start with `\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]`.

Comment: Great, that did the job!